# connect remotely to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, virtualbox

I setup a Windows 7 on `vm` on the same `pc`, I have a form with the following code:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER = 127.0.0.1; DATABASE = my_test; UID = root; PASSWORD = 'XXXX';");

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM info", connection);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(reader[1].ToString());
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

on my `pc` i successfully connect to the db, now i copy and paste my app to the vm and i get a `jit` error i don't have any thing on the `vm` (no `appache` no `mysql` nothing but net framework 4.0)
i did make my root user remote enabled like that:

`GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

now i still stuck, so how to connect to the db with my `ip` so the `vm` can find it, and do i need to setup anything in the `vm`?

Note: i can use another `pc` if the problem in the `VirtualBox` but i suspect that it has nothing to do with the `VirtualBox`.

i am confused i made this form

[image]

and i move it to the vm and i asking simply: what to write in that textbox?

Comment: What about giving us the jit error you get ?

Comment: I meant the actual error, not a screenshot where we see nothing, search for it into your event log.

Comment: i don't have a visual studio in the vm so how to know where is the error

Comment: It's called [Event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to `127.0.0.1`, you connect to the current system. Regardless of what system is running: main or `vm`. You should configure network settings of the `VirtualBox` so that `vm` can connect to your main system. In this case you'll connect from `vm` not to localhost but to IP-address that you set to main `OS`.

Or you can setup `MySQL` to the `vm` and move your database to that `MySQL`.

**EDIT**

For testing connection to `MySQL` you can use `telnet` (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/telnet-faq#1TC=windows-7). 
At first you should know the `MySQL` port. You can get it from `MySQL` config or try ports from @Prageeth Roshane' answer. Then you should try to connect from `VirtualBox` to `MySQL` to finded port. You can use or programm or telnet. If you'll have troubles with connections, try to check that the firewall in VM and in main OS is not blocked your programm (or telnet).

P.S. If you can connect to `MySQL` from another PC, but cann't connect from VM, then trouble is in VM's network settings.

Comment: the whole point is to connect to the db in my pc from another pc, i did configure the network settings so vm can access the internet

Comment: So you should connect to IP-address of your main system.

Comment: do you mean to replace `127.0.0.1` with my ip?

Comment: replace 127.0.0.1 with the ip of the host computer

Comment: Yes! When you connect to `127.0.0.1` from vm, you try to connect to `MySQL` in vm. 127.0.0.1 always are IP-address of localhost for every OS except some exotic OS.

Comment: i did change it to my public ip but i can't open it in the vm

Comment: Try to connect to public IP with telnet. And try to check of firewall in `vm`.

Answer (score -1):

Give a `PORT` that your mysql connection is using
like 3308 or 3306

Comment: how to know witch one are

Comment: You can try to connect from main OS with telnet to `127.0.0.1:3308` and to `127.0.0.1:3306`.

Comment: do i have to change anything with firewall?

Comment: @Indian how to include it in my connection string?

Comment: `Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`. More details you can find here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: ok i did this but same result: '"SERVER = my_public_IP; Port=3306; DATABASE = my_test; UID = root; Pwd=xxxx;"'