# remote connection to a mysql db fail

Tags: c#, mysql, database, remote-access

I wan't to establish a remote connection from PC#2 to a database in PC#1.

PC1:

1. setup mysql server and workbench.
2. Set password to the root user, UPDATE mysql.user SET Password =
   Password('123') WHERE user = 'root';
3. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
4. Create database CREATE DATABASE my_test;
5. CREATE TABLE info (id int(11), name nvarchar(50));
6. from ipconfig in cmd get my_ip
7. Edit my.ini add # bind-address= "my_ip"
8. from firewall inbound role open 3306.

PC2:

1. setup mysql server and workbench.
2. Connect to that my_test: workbench: hostname = my_ip, password = 123, Username = root
                            cmd: mysql -u root -h my_ip -p 123
                            connection string: Server=my_ip;Port=3306;Database=my_test;UID=root;PWD=123;

and it gives me a jit error :

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect
>   to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

also from cmd in PC#2 :

> mysql -u root -h MyIp -p
>
> Error 2003 Can't connect to Mysql server on "myIp"

i can't understand why i can't do it i did ask the same question over and over:

- [connect remotly to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684351/connect-remotly-to-mysql)
- [remote connection to mysql](https://superuser.com/questions/734293/remote-connection-to-mysql) (superuser.com)
- [remote connection to mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61888/remote-connection-to-mysql) (dba.stackexchange.com)
- [remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687358/remote-connection-to-mysql)
- [jit error while connecting to mysql remotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729309/jit-error-while-connecting-to-mysql-remotly)

i also followed this videos step by step and still get the same errors:

- [Episode 19 - How To Enable Remote Access To MySQL Server on Windows Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5qQDm3ciDg)
- [MySQL - Remote Access to MySQL Server on Linux CentOS 6.3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrRQcZeXUhQ)
- [MySQL how to install and setup for local and remote users](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEuq6E7Z2l0)

Comment: You need to pass the IP of PC1 not PC2 to the connection. The database is on PC1, right?

Comment: okay right i was passing the wrong ip then

Comment: Firewall on port 3306?

Comment: on what pc, and is it inbound or outbound rule?

Comment: on pc1 inbound.... it should accept calls on that port coming from your local network

Comment: did it now, but still the same result

Comment: it takes longer but eventually the same error

Comment: Point 8. It is a typo? Default port is 3306 not 4066